# Open PreferenceActivity using virtual button?

Tags: android, onkeydown

I'm quite new to android develompent and I'm trying to figure out how to take users to my `PreferenceActivity`. I already created a Preferences class with it's corresponding layout however I cannot figure out how to take users to this Activity on phones without a physical menu button.

I'm using a Nexus 4 and it doesn't even have a physical menu button. I've seen the menu button (three vertical dots) pop up now and then on the virtual buttons (bottom right), how can I make that button appear on the phone and take users to settings onkeydown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've seen the menu button (three vertical dots) pop up now and then on the virtual buttons (bottom right)

What you are seeing is the "legacy menu button":

[image]
<sub>(source: [blogspot.com](http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-u-3KNfy5n9M/TyG235X2rGI/AAAAAAAABHM/g_qGEXBdJW8/s400/image00.png))</sub>

It's a bad practice to still have that in your apps. It should get removed when you set your `targetSdkVersion` to API 11 or higher in your Android Manifest. It should then get shifted to the `ActionBar`. That should look something like this:

[image]
<sub>(source: [blogspot.com](http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-KIyVJ4DBLdw/TyGbNsLn4hI/AAAAAAAABFs/xgLPIAaEP6I/s400/image01.png))</sub>

Look at the overflow menu at the upper right corner.

If you want to know more about that, then read [this](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2012/01/say-goodbye-to-menu-button.html).

---

If you want to start your `PreferenceActivity` by clicking on an item by the list that gets populated by either of these menus you have to create a menu.

Override `onCreateOptionsMenu`:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    final MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.my_menu, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

my_menu.xml:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/settings"
        android:title="Settings"
        android:showAsAction="never"/>
</menu>
```

Now override `onOptionsItemSelected`:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    switch(id) {
        case android.R.id.settings:
        // Start your Activity in here.
        break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: Yes I did. Thanks a lot. Your code was perfect I had just forgotten to add the PreferenceActivity to my AndroidManifest

Comment: @Ahmad your screenshots seem to be gone.